# Vue doesn't detect scroll event

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to use the aos library on my vue app. Apparently it doesn't detect the scroll event, because it only shows the elements on screen but not the others after scrolling.

So i thought that i could add a window scroll event listener to refresh the AOS function but seems like it doesnt fire the function.

I tried some methods:

1. Adding the listener in the mounted method of the component:

```
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      console.log('Scrolling')
    });
  }
```

2. Adding the listener in the container element. This one works but not at all, it doesn't fires constantly as expected, so i have to scroll many times to fire it once:

```
<template>
  <div class="page" @scroll="scrollFunction">
    Content...
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    scrollFunction() {
      console.log('scrolling from method')
    }
  }
</script>
```

3. Adding the window scroll listener in created and destroyed functions (i saw this in another post but doesn't work for me):

```
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollFunction);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollFunction);
  }
```

4. Adding the window scroll listener on created function from App.vue.

Answer (score 0):

the first one seems to work for me (below) can you provide the rest of the code?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n17ml46v4?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue)

Comment: i changed the position attribute of .page from absolute to relative and it works now.